# Cordova App button won't work

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have an error using my cordova app on Huawei,one of the buttons does not work and freeze my whole app.I've tested it on browser and it works same Samsung.I've used remote debug while serving my app with phonegap and the click event is missing,it listen only 'deviceready'.The other buttons have all the events handlers.Do someone have an ideea about this error and why I have it on Huawei?
The full code of the button

```
 //ADD NEW CATEGORY
    $("#submit").on('click',addNewCategory);

    function addNewCategory(){
            event.stopPropagation();

       if(myAux==0 && myAux2==0){
         //show buttons
         showInputMenu();
         myAux2=1;
       }
       else if(myAux==0 && myAux2==1){
         //hide buttons
         hideInputMenu();
         myAux2=0;
       }

      else if(myAux==1){
      //get the value of the input and add it to the array
      var inputValue=$("#value").val();
      var result=checkCategory(inputValue);
      if( result == 0)
      {
        var titleArrGet = localStorage.getItem("titleArrGet");
        titleArrGet = (titleArrGet) ? JSON.parse(titleArrGet) : [];
        titleArrGet.push(inputValue);
        //save the new array in local storage
        localStorage.setItem("titleArrGet",JSON.stringify(titleArrGet));
        //update the content from right
        var newTitle=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("titleArrGet"));
        var li=$("<li></li>").text(newTitle[newTitle.length-1]);
        var div=$("<div></div>").addClass("listRectangle");
        li.append(div);
        $("#categoryList").append(li);
        //update the page content (or just use location.reload())
        var h1=$("<h1></h1>").text(newTitle[newTitle.length-1]);
        h1.append($("<i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>"));
        var ul=$("<ul></ul>");
        ul.append(h1);
        $("#myMusicList").append(ul);
        //empty the input field
        $("#value").val('');
        hideInput();

      }//end if statement
    else if(result == 1){
          $("#popUp p").text("The category already exist")
          $("#popUp").css('top','0px');
          setTimeout(function(){
              $("#popUp p").text("")
              $("#popUp").stop().css('top','-100px');
              },3000);
          }//end else statement
    else
      {
      //hide menu
      hideInput();
      hideInputCategory();

        }//end main else statement
   };//end function
}
```

Comment: Maybe post some code of that button..........

Comment: I did and I mention that other event listeners like these are working.